# About preemptive and non-preemptive kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

Here is my point about preemptive and non-preemptive kernel. As the interruption handling process is implemented in the kernel, does it imply that nested interruption can only happen in a preemptive kernel?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does it mean to say "linux kernel is preemptive" ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283501/what-does-it-mean-to-say-linux-kernel-is-preemptive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  "pre-emptive" versus "non-pre-emptive" kernels are referring to kernel code being prempted by code not running in interrupt context.  Interrupts are special, and even "non-pre-emptive" kernels typically allow kernel code to be preempted by interrupt handlers (and often even allow nested interrupts).